# Как создать venv без необходимости его обновления?

Tags: python, linux, virtualenv, зависимости

Есть проект, который использует стандартный `venv`-воркфлоу:

```
python -m venv my_venv
source my_venv/bin/activate
pip install dependency
```

Команды создают ссылку `my_venv/bin/python` на **текущий установленный** питон в системе. Однако  зависимости помещаются в директорию с **конкретной версией** питона (например, `my_venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dependency`).

Теперь, когда мой дистрибутив обновляет версию питона на 3.10, все скрипты, вызывающие `my_venv/bin/python main.py`, ломаются, т.к. эта ссылка уже указывает на новую версию питона, а зависимостей в `my_venv` для этой новой версии нет.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependency'

Как сделать так, чтобы не надо было чинить `venv` при каждом обновлении питона? Необходимо либо как-то привязаться к конкретной версии питона с зависимостями для этой версии или (лучше) к самой новой версии питона, которая будет использовать уже имеющиеся зависимости прошлой версии.

Comment: Нужно пересоздать virtualenv.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA ну желание в том, чтобы этого не делать при каждом обновлении питона

Comment: Это технически невозможно, некоторые пакеты привязаны к конкретной версии питона

Comment: @andreymal как привязаны? В `setup.py`? Допустим, мои зависимости не привязаны к прошлой версии и я могу выполнить `python path/to/old/dependency` с новым питоном без ошибок. Тогда должно быть возможно

Comment: Привязаны путём компиляции сишных (или не только сишных) библиотек пакетов под конкретные API и ABI конкретной версии CPython. Если среди ваших зависимостей нет таких пакетов, то, возможно, вам везёт, только вот я не думаю, что ради вашего частного случая кто-то будет реализовывать возможность смены версии питона в виртуальных окружениях

Comment: @andreymal я правильно понимаю, что если у меня есть 100 проектов на компе, то я должен после каждого обновления питона пересоздавать все 100 виртуальных окружений и это нормальная практика?

Comment: Как я уже ранее сказал, в любом случае некоторые зависимости придётся обязательно переустанавливать под новую версию питона, так что в общем случае вы от этого никуда не денетесь. Но если вас это тяготит, вам никто не запрещает устанавливать несколько версий питона одновременно (прямо сейчас на моём домашнем компьютере установлены 2.7, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9 и 3.10)

Comment: Вы не уточнили свой дистрибутив, но если вдруг у вас что-то на базе Ubuntu, то есть репозиторий [ppa deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) с разными версиями питона (для Ubuntu 22.04 — от 3.7 до 3.11)

Comment: @andreymal ок, тогда проще будет использовать 2 версии: 1 новую и вторую стабильную, к которой привязаны венвы

Comment: Нормальная практика это обновлять постепенно и тестировать по ходу. Чтоб не обновлять все 100 сразу нужна нормальная изоляция, используйте docker или pyenv. Пробовать как-то переключить версию без пересоздания, наверно, можно но это непереносимо и не поддерживается из коробки, на свой страх и риск.

Answer (score 0):

```
  --copies              Try to use copies rather than symlinks, even when symlinks are the default for the platform.
```

Чтоб создавать виртуальное окружение без ссылок - копируй питон с этой опцией.

```
python -m venv --copies my_venv
```

В этом случае окружение не будет  обновляться вместе с системой. Версия питона останется старой. Но это не поможет в 2022 году.

venv и virtualenv не копирует стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: На винде не проверял, но в моём линуксе с опцией `--copies` в виртуальном окружении получился 14КБ бинарник bin/python, который считывает обычный системный `/usr/lib/libpython3.10.so.1.0` (который очевидно исчезнет после обновления системного питона), ну и стандартная библиотека тоже не копируется

Comment: Спасибо, это будет первый возможный вариант (привязаться к конкретной версии питона с зависимостями для этой версии). Можно ли второй вариант как-то сделать? Чтобы версия питона осталась ссылкой, но зависимости лежали в отвлечённой от версии директории (типа `my_venv/lib/python/` или `my_venv/lib/python3/`)

Comment: @andreymal я использовал из собранного из исходников питона когда нужны были фишки 3.5 на системах где его нет

Comment: @andreymal  проверю, может ещё что-то надо дополнительно сделать.